# Rendering of uiOutput in shinyWidget::dropdownButton

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `uiOutput` in a `shinyWidget::dropdownButton`. My problem is that outputs which depend on the control in `uiOutput` are not rendered before I click the dropdown button.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dropdownButton(uiOutput("placeholder"), icon = icon("cog")),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$placeholder <- renderUI(selectInput("dat", "Select Data:",
                             choices = c("mtcars", "ChickWeight")))
   output$out <- renderPrint(summary(get(req(input$dat))))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this app you see that the summary table is only shown after I have clicked the dropdown button for the first time. From a reactive flow I guess it makes sense, but I would like to know how I force the `uiOutput` to render (such that the subsequent `out` verbatim can render)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$placeholder <- renderUI(selectInput("dat", "Select Data:",
                                             choices = c("mtcars", "ChickWeight")))
  outputOptions(output, "placeholder", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  output$out <- renderPrint(summary(get(req(input$dat))))
}
```

Comment: +1 Perfect, I hade something like this in the back of my head, but could not remember it anymore. Thanks.